# Average word length in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a list of values and their aggregated lengths of all their occurrences as an array.

Ex: If my sentence is

```
"I have a cat. The cat looks very cute"
```

My array looks like

```
Array((I,1), (have,4), (a,1), (cat,6), (The, 3), (looks, 5), (very ,4), (cute,4))
```

Now I want to compute the average length of each word. i.e the length / number of occurrences.

I tried to do the coding using Scala as follows:

```
val avglen = arr.reduceByKey( (x,y) => (x, y.toDouble / x.size.toDouble) )
```

I'm getting an error as follows at `x.size`

> error: value size is not a member of Int

Please help me where I'm going wrong here.

Comment: I'm looking for average length of each word (not at overall text level)            i.e if the number of occurrences of a word is more, I need to get average length of the word more. For example the word cat in my paragraph appeared twice so, the average length for that word is 6/3 =2  for other words such as "The", the average length is 3/3 =1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your comment I think I got it:

```
val words = sc.parallelize(Array(("i", 1), ("have", 4), 
                                 ("a", 1), ("cat", 6), 
                                 ("the", 3), ("looks", 5), 
                                 ("very", 4), ("cute", 4)))

val avgs = words.map { case (word, count) => (word, count / word.length.toDouble) }

println("My averages are: ")
avgs.take(100).foreach(println)
```

[image]

Supposing you have a paragraph with those words and You want to calculate the mean size of the words of the paragraph.

In two steps, with a `map-reduce` approach and in `spark-1.5.1`:

```
val words = sc.parallelize(Array(("i", 1), ("have", 4), 
                                 ("a", 1), ("cat", 6), 
                                 ("the", 3), ("looks", 5), 
                                 ("very", 4), ("cute", 4)))

val wordCount = words.map { case (word, count) => count}.reduce((a, b) => a + b)
val wordLength = words.map { case (word, count) => word.length * count}.reduce((a, b) => a + b)

println("The avg length is: " +  wordLength / wordCount.toDouble)
```

I ran this code using an .ipynb connected to a `spark-kernel` this is the output.

[image]

Comment: This isn't the average length of all words. The value represents the aggregate count of all of the characters of that word in that sentence (not the count of the word!).

Comment: @RohanAletty I'm not sure of what He wants, this is what I understand, normally if a paragraph has some words and you want to calculate the mean this is the appropriate approach

Comment: Please see my answer, I believe it's what the poster was asking for. Essentially, word counts were already aggregated so the keys are unique.

Comment: Thank you Eugene Zhulenev, Rohan Aletty, @Alberto Bonsanto for your answers. However I'm looking for average word length by each word. i.e if the number of occurences of a word is more, I need to get average length of the word. For example the word cat in my paragraph appeared twice so, the average length is 6/3 =2

Comment: Thank you @Alberto Bonsato for the help

Comment: One quick question @AlbertoBonsanto is why the case is used here though we have a single case scenario, as I understand that we may have to use a case where there needs to be some filtering based on some decision dynamically while processing.

Comment: @VRK fast answer if you try to do it without a case it'll show an error like this `error: wrong number of parameters; expected = 1
       val x = words.map((a, b) => (a, b * 2))
`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly:

```
val rdd: RDD[(String, Int) = ???
val ave: RDD[(String, Double) = 
     rdd.map { case (name, numOccurance) => 
       (name, name.length.toDouble / numOccurance)
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly confusing question. If your data is already in an `Array[(String, Int)]` collection (presumably after a `collect()` to the driver), then you need not use any `RDD` transformations. In fact, there's a nifty trick you can run with `fold*()` to grab the average over a collection:

```
val average = arr.foldLeft(0.0) { case (sum: Double, (_, count: Int)) => sum + count } / arr.foldLeft(0.0) { case (sum: Double, (word: String, count: Int)) => sum + count / word.length }
```

Kind of long winded, but it essentially aggregates the total number of characters in the numerator and the number of words in the denominator. Run on your example, I see the following:

```
scala> val arr = Array(("I",1), ("have",4), ("a",1), ("cat",6), ("The", 3), ("looks", 5), ("very" ,4), ("cute",4))
arr: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((I,1), (have,4), (a,1), (cat,6), (The,3), (looks,5), (very,4), (cute,4))

scala> val average = ...
average: Double = 3.111111111111111
```

If you have your `(String, Int)` tuples distributed across an `RDD[(String, Int)]`, you can use [accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka) to solve this problem quite easily:

```
val chars = sc.accumulator(0.0)
val words = sc.accumulator(0.0)
wordsRDD.foreach { case (word: String, count: Int) =>
  chars += count; words += count / word.length
}

val average = chars.value / words.value
```

When running on the above example (placed in an `RDD`), I see the following:

```
scala> val arr = Array(("I",1), ("have",4), ("a",1), ("cat",6), ("The", 3), ("looks", 5), ("very" ,4), ("cute",4))
arr: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((I,1), (have,4), (a,1), (cat,6), (The,3), (looks,5), (very,4), (cute,4))

scala> val wordsRDD = sc.parallelize(arr)
wordsRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:14

scala> val chars = sc.accumulator(0.0)
chars: org.apache.spark.Accumulator[Double] = 0.0

scala> val words = sc.accumulator(0.0)
words: org.apache.spark.Accumulator[Double] = 0.0

scala> wordsRDD.foreach { case (word: String, count: Int) =>
     |   chars += count; words += count / word.length
     | }
...
scala>     val average = chars.value / words.value
average: Double = 3.111111111111111
```